# How to add an Angular directive to rows in grid dynamically?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, grid, draggable, devextreme

I have my DxDataGrid (DevExtreme) in an Angular 7 application and want add my custom directive for each data row. What options do I have? What is recommended?

Without the directive, or before I created it, this was my code:

```
onRowPrepared(e) {
  if (e.rowType === 'data') {
    // console.log(e);
    e.rowElement.classList.add('draggable');
  }
}
```

I want to insert a directive instead of a class. Something like:

```
e.rowElement.attributes.add('appDraggable')
```

Where 'appDraggable' is my directive that will make my rows draggable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should try to solve this via a template instead of adding classes or attributes via the `HtmlElement` or `NativeElement` objects

Comment: Do you have any hints or links to guide me? I'm not that an experienced angular developer.